# how to avoid strong reference in callback of UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am creating a alert view controller with action by following code

```
var alertView = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NVConstant.alertInfoBtnTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: alertHandler))
```

And My alert Handler code is following:

```
@lazy var alertHandler:(UIAlertAction!)->Void = { a![enter image description here][1]ction in
    var clickedButtonTitle:String = action.title
    switch clickedButtonTitle{
    case NVConstant.notificationAlertConfirmatinTitle :
        Utility.cancelAlarmForTheActivity(activity: self.selectedActivity.0)
    case NVConstant.notificationAlertCancelTitle :
        self.selectedSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
    default :
        return
    }

}
```

So my question is how to avoid strong reference of self in callback closure. I tried by using [unowned self] but after that application crash i think due to parameter mismatch.

```
@lazy var alertHandler:(UIAlertAction!)->Void = { [unowned self] action in  //Crash 
// code
}
```

Following is Crash :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfgNi.png

So how can i avoid strong reference here?

Comment: What specifically was the crash?

Comment: Things are changing fast. How does it behave with beta6?

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for the reply i added a image url of the crash.

Comment: It is working fine with beta 6.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewritting the closure like this..

```
@lazy var alertHandler:(UIAlertAction!)->Void = { [unowned self] (UIAlertAction: action) -> () in

}
```

Comment: Hi Ernesto thanks for the reply but tried this as well and application crash in same way

Comment: This is the correct syntax, however you should know that this can be avoided if the owner of the controller is the function (not the controller). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34931631/654870