# Should self be captured as strong in a UIAlertAction's handler?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

When writing the `handler` closure of a `UIAlertAction`, should the reference to `self` be strong (the default), `weak`, or `unowned`?

There have been posts relevant to this topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975073/swift-closures-capturing-self-as-weak), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042949/block-retain-cycles-in-swift), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936264/why-specify-unowned-self-in-blocks-where-you-depend-on-self-being-there)) but I honestly don't see how they help in this case.

Let's focus on this typical code:

```
func tappedQuitButton() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm quit", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let quitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Quit", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addAction(quitAction)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is a function inside a `UIViewController` subclass, so `self` is the view controller presenting the alert.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) says:

> Use a weak reference to avoid reference cycles whenever it is possible for that reference to have “no value” at some point in its life. If the reference will always have a value, use an unowned reference instead.

I may be blind, but I still don't see how this helps answering my question about `UIAlertAction`.

In the above code, is it possible for `self` to be nil *at some point in its life*? Yes. So I should mark `self` as `weak`.

But then again, I can't think of a plausible scenario where `self` will be nil when the closure is called. So as far as that closure is concerned, `self` *will always have a value*. So I should mark `self` as `unowned`.

So, again, how should `self` be captured in a UIAlertAction's handler?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The key question to ask yourself is if your alert object is "owned" by self. In this case, it is not (because you declared `let alert = ...` in the function body). So you do not need to create this as a weak or unowned reference.

If alert was a property of self, then it would be "owned" by self and that is when you would want to create a weak reference to self in the closure "owned" by the alert.

Comment: I have a tough time seeing this in terms of "ownership". Why aren't the local variables in an instance method "owned" by the instance calling it..?

Comment: The local variables are allocated on the stack... and will only live for the lifetime of the stack/function. Once you've created it, it is up to the presenting view controller to manage its lifetime once it goes out of scope of the function it is called in. In this case the alert needs to hold onto self, but self could care less about the alert once the function has been called, something else (the presenting view controller) is taking care of it.

Comment: Therefore, if the alert is a local variable it's always ok to keep a strong reference to self, otherwise if the alert is a property then it should keep a weak reference to self. Correct?

Comment: @GoodDoug but when you present it, the `presentedViewController` will be the alert, this may cause retain cycle

Comment: you didn't answer the question. How would you put [weak weakSelf = self] into the handler along with the argument action in the closure.

Comment: @onmyway133 yes `presentViewController` will retain `alert`. And when `alertController` presented from `self`, why would you dealloc `self`? It is not the current view controller any more. You have to dismiss the `alertController` first. And when you do that, the retain will be release. So no retain cycle any more.

Comment: This simple rule is appropriate in this case. I've written a code and tested it in Xcode 7.3, iOS 9

Comment: Thank you. First explanation that has made sense to me.